# How to serve static content in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, static

I am using spring-mvc framework in my current project. ROOT folder has lots of web folders containing html, jsp, css, js etc. My spring mvc configuration is as follows:

```
<context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="comicControllerBean" class="tv.cinemacraft.videogramwebapp.springmvc.controllers.ComicController" />
    <bean id="dashboardControllerBean" class="tv.cinemacraft.videogramwebapp.springmvc.controllers.DashBoardController" />
    <bean id="genericControllerBean" class="tv.cinemacraft.videogramwebapp.springmvc.controllers.GenericController" />
    <bean id="channelControllerBean" class="tv.cinemacraft.videogramwebapp.springmvc.controllers.ChannelController" />

    <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="tv.cinemacraft.videogramwebapp.springmvc.controllers" /> -->

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
        <property name="basename" value="views" />
        <property name="order" value="0" />
    </bean>
```

And I have mapping defined in my java controller. But this is causing static content like any image to vanish. If I request for any image inside any folder by accessing ROOT//.jpg, it gives me 404 response code although image exists. 
If I remove spring-mvc, image gets displayed.

Note that spring-mvc's resources attribute works for static content but that need my static content to be present inside particular folder e.g. resouce folder. So this approach is not useful for me.

Comment: can you dump this approach for better, robust and simplified one i.e. Spring Boot ? things will get lot easier with Spring boot and plain Java Programming rather than these bloated XML configurations. If yes then i will post all the directory structure and required Annotations and code for accessing static content. :)

Comment: sorry but our project is totally in spring-mvc

Comment: Spring mvc is framework, while spring boot is application setting up approach, for spring mvc project. http://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s say you have a directory `(/resources/my_images/)` that contains some product images, and you want to serve these images upon request. For example, if the requested URL is `http://localhost:8080/ mystore/resource/my_images/P123.png`, then you would like to serve the image with the `P123.png` name. Similarly, if the requested URL is `http://localhost:8080/mystore/resource/images/P1234.png`, then an image with the name `P1234.png` needs to be served.

**Now how you can serve static images with Spring MVC?**

1. Place some images under the `src/main/webapp/resources/my_images/` directory;
2. Add the following tag in our web application context’s configuration
   `DispatcherServlet-context.xml` file: `<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resource/**"/>`
3. run your application and enter
   `http://localhost:8080/mystore/resource/images/P123.png` (change the
   image name in the URL based on the images you placed

FYI: `<mvc:resources>` tag in the web application context configuration to tell Spring where these image files are located in our project so that spring can serve those files upon request.

Comment: Hello Georges,  Issue with the above implementation is that my webapp folder structure does not contain resource folder. And we don't want to create resource folder. It should automatically pick the image file from where ever the image is placed under. E.g. `http://localhost:8080/somepath/someimg.jpg` In this case spring mvc framework intercepts the request and thus since there is no handler returns 404.

Comment: so you just do this something like : <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/**/"/>  Just remove the resource . !! leave the other resources because its springs default map for static content. Notice de difference btw resources and resource

Comment: Ok I will try and let you know

Comment: Hello Georges, I have tried this configuration my original problem of serving static content is solved but it has raised another issue that now it is giving non static urls are 404 not found.

Comment: Hey prashant, please open a new and well detailed question